PHP 8.1 Mysqli Execute throwing Uncaught ArgumentCountError
Environment:
Ubuntu 20.04
PHP 8.1.28
MySQL 5.7.12
Newrelic 10.19.0.9 (I have found issues with newrelic that seemed promising, but turning off newrelic didn't help). Reference: https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-php-agent/issues/875
I have recently upgraded to PHP 8.1, I am still doing the bind_param function before the execute function and that bind_param call works just fine, but there is an intermittent issue with the execute function. Why is the execute function calling bind_param when I am already doing this? I could just send the params into the execute instead and it seems to work, but I don't understand why I would have to do this. I also worry about the potential problems this would cause as it treats all params as a string and all of my queries are now going through this function. Below is the error, stack trace, and some example code that I am using.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: The number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement in Database.php:548
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: mysqli_stmt->bind_param()
#1 Database.php(548): mysqli_stmt->execute()
#2 Database.php(60): Database->_query()
#3 ReportService.php(2295): Database->getAll()
#4 automated-emails.php(127): ReportService->loadSalesReportData()
#5 {main}
  thrown in Database.php on line 548

    $bindParamTypes = '';
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        switch (gettype($param)) {
            case 'boolean':
            case 'integer':
                $bindParamTypes .= 'i';
                break;
            case 'double':
                $bindParamTypes .= 'd';
                break;
            case 'NULL':
            case 'string':
                $bindParamTypes .= 's';
                break;
            default:
                throw new \Exception('cannot bind param of type ' . gettype($param));
        }
    }

    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);

    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new \Exception($this->mysqli->error);
    }

    if (count($params) > 0) {
        $response = $stmt->bind_param($bindParamTypes, ...$params);
    }

    $ok = $stmt->execute();


In case it's a PHP bug, then "some example code" is not enough. You need to provide a complete working  code snippet that gives you this error. Along with exact PHP version you are using

As this is an intermittent issue, a complete working code snippet will likely not be enough either. I am hoping that the brain trust of stack overflow may have had similar issues upgrading to PHP 8.1. I have added more details on the environment. As you can see by the stack trace, it is dying on the "internal function" which has made this difficult to debug. My debugger doesn't step into core code...

Yes, I would bet on newrelic, it's not the first time it does such things. Are you 100% sure it is turned off?

I will keep this question closed, just to prevent silly answers and leave it for the Dharman's judgement

You were right. Thanks for being my rubber duck lol. I had only turned it off through the apache php.ini. I needed to turn it off for the cli php.ini. Interestingly, I have the most up to date version of Newrelic, but they supposedly fixed this issue a couple of weeks ago. Maybe they haven't released a version with the fix in it yet?
